# Rails 3: How to respond_with csv without having a template file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have an object that has a `to_csv` method and I want to pass it to `respond_with` to render csv from my controller.  My code looks like this:

```
class Admin::ReportsController < AdminController

  respond_to :csv

  def trips
    respond_with TripReport.new
  end
end
```

Instances of TripReport have a to_csv method.

When I make a request to that action I get the following error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template admin/reports/trips with {:formats=>[:csv], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
```

So it looks like the controller is looking for a template file to render.  How can I get around this?

I'd rather the csv format responded in a similar way to json, so it calls `to_csv` on the object and just renders the output, is this possible?

Comment: Hi Oliver, did you have any luck with figuring this out?  I'm running into the same problem here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been struggling with the exact same problem. I might have found a solution.

I found some clues while reading the Renderers.add source code for :json and :xml (link is for Rails 3.0.10 code, 3.1 might have some changes already):
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.10/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb

First, add a simple `as_csv` method to your model definition:

```
class Modelname < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def as_csv
    attributes
  end
end
```

This can be anything, just make sure to return a hash with key/value pairs. A Hash works better than an Array, as with keys you're able to add a header row to the CSV output later on. The idea for `as_csv` comes from Rails' `as_json` method, which return a Ruby object that is used by `to_json` to generate the actual JSON (text) output.

With the `as_csv` method in place, put the following code in a file in `config/initializers` inside your app (name it `csv_renderer.rb`, for example):

```
require 'csv' # adds a .to_csv method to Array instances

class Array 
  alias old_to_csv to_csv #keep reference to original to_csv method

  def to_csv(options = Hash.new)
    # override only if first element actually has as_csv method
    return old_to_csv(options) unless self.first.respond_to? :as_csv
    # use keys from first row as header columns
    out = first.as_csv.keys.to_csv(options)
    self.each { |r| out << r.as_csv.values.to_csv(options) }
    out
  end
end

ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |csv, options|
  csv = csv.respond_to?(:to_csv) ? csv.to_csv() : csv
  self.content_type ||= Mime::CSV
  self.response_body = csv
end
```

And finally, add CSV support to your controller code:

```
class ModelnamesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json, :csv

  def index
    @modelnames = Modelname.all
    respond_with(@modelnames)
  end

  # ...

end
```

The initializer code is largely based on the :json and :xml behaviour from the Rails source code (see link above).

Currently, the `options` hash passed to the block doesn't get passed to the `to_csv` call, as CSV is quite picky on which options it allows to be sent. Rails adds some default options by itself (like :template and some others), which gives you an error when passing them to `to_csv`. You can change the default CSV rendering behaviour by adding your own preferred CSV options to the initializer, of course.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question but here's an updated method for the custom Renderer for newer versions of Rails (currently using 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3) taken from the ActionController::Renderers documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderers.html#method-c-add

As florish said, create an initializer but add this code:

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |obj, options|
  filename = options[:filename] || 'data'
  str = obj.respond_to?(:to_csv) ? obj.to_csv : obj.to_s
  send_data str, :type => Mime::CSV,
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{filename}.csv"
end
```

And use it as such:

```
def show
  @csvable = Csvable.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { render :csv => @csvable, :filename => @csvable.name }
  end
end
```

I take no credit for the code above, it's straight from the documentation, but this worked for me in Rails 3.2.11 so pointing it out for people coming across this thread for the first time.

In my project I'm not using a to_csv method, I'm actually building the CSV manually first. So here's what mine looks like:

```
def show
  items = Item.where(something: true)
  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    # header row
    csv << %w(id name)
    # add a row for each item
    items.each do |item|
      csv << [item.id, item.name]
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv { render :csv => csv_string, :filename => "myfile.csv" }
  end
end
```

You should obvious move the CSV creation code to some other class or model but putting it here inline just to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

I think your model would have to have a `to_csv` method that returns the attributes as csv.

After that, if Rails doesn't call the `to_csv` method implicitly, I would try

```
respond_with TripReport.new.to_csv
```

Comment: As I said, my object responds to `to_csv`.  Passing in a string to respond_with doesn't work, it is expecting something that can respond to `to_#{format}`

Answer (score 2):

First create a renderer for the CSV mime type in `config/initializers/csv_renderer.rb`

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :csv do |collection, options|
  self.content_type ||= Mime::CSV
  self.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{options[:filename]}.csv" if options[:filename]
  self.response_body = collection.to_csv
end
```

Then add a `to_csv` method to your model. If your data is an array or hash you might consider creating a new class for that collection with its own to_csv and to_json methods, instead of having everything in the controller. If its an ActiveRecord model you can use the following in an initializer:

```
require 'csv'

module CsvRenderer
  def to_csv(options={})
    columns = column_names
    columns += options[:include] if options[:include]
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << columns
      all.pluck(*columns).each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.extend CsvRenderer
```

You can then pass an ActiveRecord relation to respond_with:

```
def index
  respond_with(Item.all, filename: 'items')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into what I would guess is a similar problem to what you were experiencing, Oliver. I realized that in my routes file I was using `resource` instead of `resources`.  I do not know if you have other actions in your Admin::ReportsController class or what your routes file looks like, but this is how I would tackle the problem if Reports has the standard REST actions.

```
scope :module => 'Admin' do
  resources :reports do
    get :trips, :on => :collection
  end
end
```

If that does not apply, run `rake routes` to see if your routes are configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to implement another view with all data you want.

```
# controller code
respond_to :html, :csv

def index
  respond_with Person.all
end

# view
views/persons/index.csv.erb
```