# Adding a Renderer for VCF in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to add a renderer to allow one of my models to respond to the .vcf format. I have added the following code to my `vcf_renderer.rb` file which is in my `initializers` directory:

```
Mime::Type.register 'text/x-vcard', :vcf
ActionController::Renderers.add :vcf do |object, options|
  exit! # Testing to see if this even gets called at all...
end
```

It seems as if the following code is never even being executed because if I go to /model/123.vcf I get at **"Template is Missing"** error.

Does anyone know why the `ActionController::Renderers.add` block doesn't seem to be called?

AuthorsController.rb

```
respond_to :vcf

def show

  respond_with(@author)

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the old style works, executing the renderer `format.vcf  { render :vcf => @object }`.

With `respond_with` (which now raises "Missing template") you have to [add a to_vcf method in the models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182344/rails-3-how-to-respond-with-csv-without-having-a-template-file). Tried for `show` and it worked (for `index` it doesn't recognize `to_vcf` for arrays).

```
# config/initializers/vcf_renderer.rb
Mime::Type.register 'text/x-vcard', :vcf
ActionController::Renderers.add :vcf do |object, options|
  self.content_type ||= 'text/x-vcard'
  self.response_body  = object.respond_to?(:to_vcf) ? object.to_vcf : object
end
```

Comment: I've added a `respond_to :vcf` to the top of my controller.

Comment: That's right, didn't see it. On a new Rails 3.0.7 app this code works here, the browser asks me to download a card, and the server exits.

Comment: I've upgraded to 3.0.7 and this still is not working for me. It doesn't ask me to download a card. It just says that I'm missing a VCF template file, which I don't want to have to provide; Hence the `ActionController::Renderers.add`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's interesting. In my application, if I try with respond_with, it raises "missing template". With old style format.vcf, it triggers initializers/vcf_renderer.rb. Something to investigate, but can you try with the old syntax? (Updated my answer.)

Comment: There we go, had to add to_vcf method in models.