# How exactly does rails respond_to work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am currently building an application that needs remote form, and it came across me that I never really understood how rails `respond_to` work.

For example, I have the following code in the view

```
<%= form_tag ..., :remote => true %>
<%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And I have a javascript partial named `_home.js.erb`, suppose the action related is named `home`.

I understand that if I have the following code in my controller:

```
def home
    # ...
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :partial => 'home' }
    end
end
```

This will execute the javascript in `_home.js.erb` when the submit button for the form is pressed. However, what exactly is going on when the submit button is pressed? How exactly does rails know whether to `respond_to` html or javascript?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The [Responder](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/82a8698e564e5c27ac3516f0b44449a74b4389be/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb#L212) object renders content if the headers indicate that it is of type

- html
- js

else, a magic method is invoked that calls a object.method that is the name of the respond type (e.g. `csv`)

This requires that such a method is defined as a handler of the response type.  [A good discussion of how to create custom responders was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182344/rails-3-how-to-respond-with-csv-without-having-a-template-file).

Answer (score 0):

The submit button posts the form with certain headers/mimes set. `respond_to` decided how to act based on the content type, verb and the resource status of the request.

See here for details: [ActionController::Responder < Object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html)

Comment: then can I effectively do something like this in the application.js?

    `$(document).ready(function(){$('#submit').on('click', ...);});`

To achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Enzo it is a confusing question

Comment: also does this mean that if `:remote => true` is removed or set to false. then the submit button will post the form with a header/mime set that tells the responder to respond in HTML?

Comment: @NewAlexandria I will rephrase my question below... Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

In the options hash the `remote: true` is requesting Rails to respond with javascript.

If you have a web inspector, you check out your network tab, submit the form, and you can see that in the http request headers that the post request is requesting javascript in the accept field. If you did not have the remote tag in the options hash, your form submission would be requesting html.

Additionally, if you do a rake routes in your project directory, you'll see that almost every route ends with the .:format keyword `/posts(.:format)` that allows your controller to respond to multiple types of formats a user could potentially define in the specific controller.